# Emulate nested <img> in <h1> without actually nesting

Tags: html, css, layout, nested

I've got to fix a page that has an href image in the h1 tag, like so:

```
<h1>Header text <a href="example.com"><img src="image.png"></a></h1>
```

and the page looks fine as is. However, having a link in the h1 tag is doing bad things to my SEO, so I need to separate them. Problem is, when I take the two apart:

```
<h1>Header text</h1><a href="example.com"><img src="image.png"></a>
```

It puts the logo below the header, pushing all of the other containers down and breaking the layout of the page completely. What I want to do is use CSS to make the two elements *behave* like they're nested without actually needing to be.

Comment: `h1 {display: inline-block}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `float:left;` or `display:inline-block;` to your h1 tag so that image and header text would be in same line:

```
h1 {
  float: left;/*prefer to use inline-block though*/
}
```

---

You may also be interested with the following structure for more SEO tuning:

```
<hgroup>
  <h1>Header text</h1>
  <h1><a href="example.com"><img src="image.png"></a></h1>
</hgroup>
```

Comment: The hgroup idea worked wonders. The img element, it turned out, had a lot of CSS from h1, and using the display:inline method would have required a lot of work to get all the CSS back for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer Bhojendra Nepal is good or you could put them in two divs a right div and left div

Example here I have center, right, left:

```css
#wrapper {
  margin-right: 200px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      to right, 
      lightblue, blue, lightblue, #0008ED, lightblue
    );
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;

}

#center{
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
 }
 
 
#right{
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -60%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left"> text</div>
  <div id="center"> text</div>
  <div id="right">text</div>
  <div id="cleared"></div>
</div>
```